# Unwind Segue, scroll to bottom of UITableView after adding cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController that calls another`UIViewController`.  The only purpose of his view controller is to enter some data that is then used to create a new cell.  After inserting the cell, I want to scroll to the cell that was just added.  All that I've been able to make it do is scroll to the second to last cell.  This is my code.

```
var stringItems: [String] = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return stringItems.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel!.text = stringItems[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

@IBAction func backToTable(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    let vc = segue.sourceViewController as! AddView

    stringItems.append(vc.dataItemOne.text)

    //Insert the row
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0), inSection: 0)
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)

    //Scroll to last item in the list.  Not working.  Scrolls to second to last row.
    let pathToLastIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: 0)
    tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(pathToLastIndex, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None, animated: false)
}
```

The backToTable function is an unwind function from the `UIViewController` that collects the data to be added to the new cell.

What's happening is the cell is not actually added until after the code in backToTable is executed.  This code **is** selecting the last cell, but because the cell hasn't been added at the time the code is executed, it ends up selecting the second to last cell.

I've played around with a couple of ideas, like adding a blank cell before loading the other view, and then populating it in backToTable, but that didn't work either.  I had the same results with this way of doing it.

Any ideas on how to make this work?  The only other idea that I could come up with was setting a flag to indicate an add, and then selecting the correct cell in `viewDidAppear`.  That might work, but there has to be a better way of doing this.

I just gave this a try.  It works, but like I said, perhaps not the best way to handle it.

```
var stringItems: [String] = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q"]
var addingItem: Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    println(tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0))

    //If adding, this appears to be the place to scroll to the bottom.
    if addingItem {
        addingItem = false

        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0)-1, inSection: 0)
        let pathToLastIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: 0)
        tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(pathToLastIndex, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: true)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return stringItems.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel!.text = stringItems[indexPath.row]
    println("cellForRowAtIndexPath")
    return cell
}

@IBAction func backToTable(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    let vc = segue.sourceViewController as! AddView

    stringItems.append(vc.dataItemOne.text)

    //Insert the row
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0), inSection: 0)
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    addingItem = true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Untested) but your backToTable and viewDidAppear should look similar to this:

```
@IBAction func backToTable(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    let vc = segue.sourceViewController as! AddView
    stringItems.append(vc.dataItemOne.text)
    addingItem = true
   }

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
   if (addingItem){
      tableView.beginUpdates()

      //Insert row

      tableView.endUpdates()
      tableView.reloadData()

      //Scroll to last row
      addingItem = false
   }
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am getting the same result.  It always selects the second to last row.  I also tried code to get a new indexPath after the insertion.  When I tried that, I got an exception that indicated that it was unable to select the newly added row.

Comment: in backToTable, update only your data model. In viewDidAppear put your insert, reload and scroll.

Comment: Updated the answer, give it a try.